# Build fails but no errors?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have a small project where I had to change a reference (dll) to a new version and when doing this and hitting build I get failed (80 errors)!? When visiting the cs files the errors disappear on their own until there are 0 left. While having the cs files open and hitting build again I still get failed but no 0 errors?

The types that it says is broken in the output is possible to follow with the F12 so they do exists!?

I have tried restart, clean, rebuild the new dll in both 32 and 64. No luck at all?

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: PopManWS, Configuration:
>   Release Any CPU ------ 1>Build started 2016-09-12 19:01:49.
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5):
>   warning MSB3274: The primary reference "MyApp.ServiceExtensions" could
>   not be resolved because it was built against the
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" framework. This is a higher version than
>   the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
>   1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: 1>Skipping target
>   "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are
>   up-to-date with respect to the input files. 1>CoreCompile: 1> 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig
>   /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt
>   /warn:4 /define:TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US
>   /highentropyva- /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\PopManWS.dll
>   /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team
>   Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule
>   Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /utf8output
>   MyAppPatient.cs Patient.cs PatientParser.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "Service References\PopManService\Reference.cs" SokPatientHandler.cs
>   "C:\Users\kalle\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>   1>  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(5,7,5,12):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(6,7,6,12):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(3,7,3,12):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\PatientParser.cs(7,7,7,12):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\SokPatientHandler.cs(5,7,5,12):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\SokPatientHandler.cs(10,7,10,12):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(7,28,7,41):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IMyAppPatient' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\PatientParser.cs(18,16,18,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IMyAppPatient' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\PatientParser.cs(28,17,28,30):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IMyAppPatient' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(10,33,10,46):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IMyAppPatient' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(9,16,9,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(11,16,11,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(13,16,13,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(15,16,15,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(17,16,17,64):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(17,22,17,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(19,16,19,32):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(21,16,21,32):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(12,16,12,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(23,16,23,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(14,16,14,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(25,16,25,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(16,16,16,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(18,16,18,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(27,16,27,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(29,16,29,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(20,16,20,64):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(20,22,20,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(31,16,31,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(33,16,33,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(22,16,22,32):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(35,16,35,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(24,16,24,32):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(37,16,37,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(26,16,26,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(39,16,39,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(28,16,28,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(30,16,30,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(41,16,41,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(32,16,32,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(43,16,43,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(34,16,34,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\SokPatientHandler.cs(16,38,16,49):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ISokPatient' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(45,16,45,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(36,16,36,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(38,16,38,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(47,16,47,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(40,16,40,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(49,16,49,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(42,16,42,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(51,16,51,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(44,16,44,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\SokPatientHandler.cs(28,77,28,96):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SearchPatientSource' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\SokPatientHandler.cs(28,16,28,21):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyApp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(53,16,53,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(46,16,46,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(48,16,48,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(55,16,55,32):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(50,16,50,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(57,16,57,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(52,16,52,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(54,16,54,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(59,16,59,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(56,16,56,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(61,16,61,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(58,16,58,32):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(63,16,63,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(60,16,60,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(65,16,65,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(62,16,62,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(67,16,67,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(64,16,64,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(66,16,66,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(68,16,68,27):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(69,16,69,35):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(70,16,70,29):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(71,16,71,31):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(72,16,72,35):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(74,16,74,31):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\Patient.cs(73,16,73,31):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\MyApp\Produkter\Integrationer\PopManWS-Blekinge\PopManWS\MyAppPatient.cs(76,16,76,31):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Value<>' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 1>
>   1>Build FAILED. 1> 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.05
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: See Output window for more details about the errors.

Comment: You could at least paste a screenshot or a message of the build failure output... can't provide much help with this little info

Comment: Go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Soltuions -> Build and Run and change "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Diagnostic" to give you more information on the build process. Please post some of the details here if possible.

Comment: Make sure `Build` is checked in configuration manager

Comment: Build is checked, this is the only project. I have included the output but it only says that the reference seems to be missing but its there? And I can use Go To Reference on the types that it is failing?

Comment: @Banshee there is a .Net version mismatch. That's why it won't build but your do see the assembly reference and you can still use Go To Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log output seems quite clear to me:

**MyApp.ServiceExtensions**" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=**v4.6**" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=**v4.0**".

The project PopManWS that references MyApp.ServiceExtensions is build using .Net v4.0. So you need to target the PopManWS project to .Net 4.6 or retarget the MyApp.ServiceExtensions project to use .Net 4.0 and rebuild.

You can only reference projects that are build against the same or a lower .Net framework version.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx on how to retarget.

Comment: Dont know how I could miss that!? Thanks for your help!

Comment: We all have our moments :-P Glad to be able to help.